# When concat date and time in php, the minutes always save as '12'

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am using forms to get the date and time before combining them and store into MySQL (datetime datatype)

However the minutes always saved as **12**.

**Here are my codes :**

```
$date = new \DateTime($model->fda_date);
$time = new \DateTime($model->fda_time);            
$merge = new \DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d') .' ' .$time->format('H:i:s'));
$model->fda_date = $merge->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$model->save();
```

**Example :**

> Date = 26-12-2016
>
> Time = 13:30:15
>
> Expected Output : 2016-12-26 13:**30**:15
>
> Actual Output : 2016-12-26 13:**12**:14

Comment: Which PHP version you use? Which OS? What is the date/time of your server/machine? It looks like everything works here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15177e000bf35dac6435f7c503842cf28ff42e8b

Comment: exactly, when i echo it out before saving, it shows the correct value. However, when it was saved in MySQL, the minutes turn to 12. 

I'm using PHP 5.6 on local MacOS. MySQL is 5.5

Comment: Found it. Upon further checking, even though the formatting was correct, in Yii2 model, i did the formatting again in beforeSave function. In the model, the formatting was incorrect accidently format it as H:m:s and not H:i:s.